# StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml doesn't work on strings read from files

Tags: java, file-io, unicode

I'm trying to read in a file that contains unicode characters, convert those characters to their corresponding symbols and then print the resulting text to a new file. I'm trying to use StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml to do this but the lines are just being printed as is, with the unicode points still intact. I did a practice run by copying a single line from the file, making a string from that and then calling StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml on that, which works perfectly. My code is below:

```
    class FileWrite 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
      String testString = " \"text\":\"Dude With Knit Hat At Party Calls Beer \u2018Libations\u2019 http://t.co/rop8NSnRFu\" ";

      FileReader instream = new FileReader("Home Timeline.txt");
      BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(instream);

      FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

      out.write(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(testString) + "\n");//This gives the desired output,
                                                                    //with unicode points converted
      String line = b.readLine().toString();

      while(line != null){
        out.write(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(line) + "\n");
        line = b.readLine();
      }

      //Close the output streams
      b.close();
      out.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//This gives the desired output,
//with unicode points converted
out.write(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(testString) + "\n");
```

You are mistaken. Java unescapes String literals of this form at compile time when it builds them into the class file:

```
"\u2018Libations\u2019"
```

There are no [HTML 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) escapes in this code. The method you have chosen is designed to unescape escape sequences of the form `&#x2018;`.

You probably want the [unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

You're strings are being both read and written using your platforms default encoding. You want to explicitly specify the character set to use as 'UTF-8':

Input stream:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("Home Timeline.txt"),
        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Output stream:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("out.txt"),
        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```